# C# WebBrowser invoke JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm trying to run a JavaScript function on a webpage from my C# codes.

This is the code from the website:

```
<div class="class34" onclick="sendpost(8);"></div><div class="class34" onclick="sendpost(9);"></div>
function sendpost(valg) {
    valget = {};
    valget.rane = valg
    poststuff('snas',valget, function(back) {
        $('#return').html(back.html);
    });
}
```

And this is the code I've tried to run it in C#:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sendpost(8)");
```

and the result is that the code does nothing, I've been searching for the correct code to use but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

How can I make my webBrowser1 either click or run the sendpost(8) function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_HtmlDocument_InvokeScript_System_String_System_Object___) is you friend.

Go with:

```
Object[] args = new Object[1];
args[0] = 8;

webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sendpost", args);
```

This will run the `sendpost` javascript method with the `valg` parameter/argument set to 8

Comment: CS0103 The name 'newObject' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry, typo ... should be `new Object`